# Minecraft Forge - Loop keeps overwriting itself

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I apologise if this is an overly simple question.

I'm making an rpg mod with 26 skills in it, all with an id from 0 to 25. I'm attempting to save the data from those skills using a for loop, but it keeps overwriting itself, and I'm not sure why or how.

```
@Override
public CompoundNBT serializeNBT() {
    CompoundNBT data = new CompoundNBT();
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        data.putInt("xp", (int) (xp[i] * 10));
        data.putInt("dynamic", dynamicLevels[i]);
        data.putInt("static", staticLevels[i]);
    }
    return data;
}
```

Comment: I think the tag names have to be unique, you should try something like "xp_"+i, xp[i]*10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments, you should use unique keys for int values you put in the data structure.

Key-value data structures (in your case it is highly probable that `CompoundNBT` is the one) often refer only one value to one key. So you should store 26 keys for xp, 26 for dynamic and 26 for static.

You can rewrite your code like:

```
@Override
public CompoundNBT serializeNBT() {
    CompoundNBT data = new CompoundNBT();

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        data.putInt("xp_"+i, (int) (xp[i] * 10));
        data.putInt("dynamic_"+i, dynamicLevels[i]);
        data.putInt("static_"+i, staticLevels[i]);
    }
    return data;
}
```

However, I assume you should go with something like

```
// Remember to fix base method too
@Override
public ArrayList<CompoundNBT> serializeNBT() {
    
    ArrayList<CompoundNBT> out = new ArrayList<>();    

    for(int i = 0; i < 26; i++) {
        CompoundNBT data = new CompoundNBT();
        data.putInt("xp", (int) (xp[i] * 10));
        data.putInt("dynamic", dynamicLevels[i]);
        data.putInt("static", staticLevels[i]);
        out.add(data);
    }
    return out;
}
```

This will give the list of "skills", each having its value

Comment: I used your first example, and now it works, thank you!